# use of undeclared identifier '_ISspace'

Tags: cmake, android-ndk, llvm-clang

I'm trying to build C library for android using android-ndk-r20.
I am using CMake to build my library.

The architecture is android-arm64

The problem is that I get the following errors during compilation:

> /home/erez/android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:382:32:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier '_ISspace'

Same error goes for all kind of macros - **_ISprint**, **_IScntrl** etc.

I have tried to look it up in Google but there is no mention of this macro, which is weird.

When I open this file I do see some use of this macros.

I have tried to look it up but I could not find any place that this macro is defined. 
It is confusing to me because I assume that the nkd/LLVM will be self contained with all the needed headers and libraries, but I cant find this header anywhere.

This is my CMake command:

> cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="-std=c++11"
>   -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=24 -DTARGET=android -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DLIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH_ROOT=`pwd`/../android_output -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`pwd`/../../../../../android-ndk-r20/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
>   -DBUILD_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) ../../rootCmake ; make VERBOSE=1  install ;

Does anyone have any idea how do I solve this?

**Edit:**

root CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(Osn)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(TARGET "android" CACHE STRING "Set the target ios mac32/64, linux32/64, android, win32/64")

# Static link the c++ library in case of a gcc compiler.
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
  include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/gcc_config.cmake)
endif()

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
  include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/darwin.cmake)
elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
  include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/linux.cmake)
elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
  include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/msvc_config.cmake)
#elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "iOS")
#  include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ios-arm.cmake)
endif()

if (${TARGET} MATCHES "android")
  include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/android.cmake)
endif()

add_subdirectory(OsnClient/OsnClient)

#if(NOT ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "iOS")
  add_subdirectory(OsnClientApp/OsnClientApp)
#endif()
```

srcs CMakelists.txt:

```
project(ProjectName)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(OSN_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(OSN_INCLUDE ${OSN_ROOT}/../../../include)
set(OSNCLIENT_EXPORTS on)


set(gabro_files ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../gabro/${TARGET} )
if (${TARGET} MATCHES android)
  set(gabro_files ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../gabro/${TARGET}-${ANDROID_ABI} )
endif()


if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES Windows)
  SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}
/NODEFAULTLIB:libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-s-1_47.lib
....
....
/VERBOSE:LIB
")
endif()

add_definitions(-DGABRO_WIN32_API_STATIC)

set(src
  ${OSN_ROOT}/src1.cpp
  ${OSN_ROOT}/src2.cpp
)

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${OSN_ROOT}
  ${gabro_files}/include
  ${OSN_INCLUDE}
)

if (${TARGET} MATCHES android)
  set(log_lib  ${ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/android-${ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL}/arch-${ANDROID_ARCH_NAME}/usr/lib )
endif()

link_directories(
  ${gabro_files}/lib
)


set(link_libs gabro_client_api_static)

if (WIN32)
  list(APPEND link_libs gabro_static_external-mt wininet )
elseif (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES Darwin)
  list(APPEND link_libs gabro_static_external pthread z dl)
elseif (${TARGET} MATCHES android)
  list(APPEND link_libs gabro_static_external libOsnClient.so log)
else()
  list(APPEND link_libs gabro_static_external pthread dl rt)
endif()

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "ios")
   add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${src})
else()
   add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${src})
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${link_libs} )

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} 
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)
```

clang++ --version:

> Android (5220042 based on r346389c) clang version 8.0.7
>   (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang
>   b55f2d4ebfd35bf643d27dbca1bb228957008617)
>   (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm
>   3c393fe7a7e13b0fba4ac75a01aa683d7a5b11cd) (based on LLVM 8.0.7svn)
>   Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu Thread model: posix

Comment: Can you share the compile command that failed (or even better, the compiler output with `-v`)? Or maybe the CMakeLists.txt? It looks like the include paths were incorrectly configured, but I can't tell why from the information given.

Comment: @DanAlbert I have added the CMake files and compiler information

Comment: `-v`, not `--verbose`. Add it to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have `__GLIBC__` defined. Android is not using glibc.

From the file in question `__locale`:

```
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS ctype_base
{
public:
#if defined(__GLIBC__)  // <-- Here's the problem
    typedef unsigned short mask;
    static const mask space  = _ISspace;
    static const mask print  = _ISprint;
    static const mask cntrl  = _IScntrl;
    static const mask upper  = _ISupper;
...
}
```